# Facebook login in classic ASP website

Tags: facebook, asp-classic

I have a Classic ASP message board (http://yankeedesi.com) where users are required to sign up for posting messages. I want to incorporate an additional functionality to login via facebook. I searched on Google but could not find any good examples for implementing this in Classic ASP. Can anyone direct me to a good source of how to do this?

I don't need any advanced functionality, just the basic login feature. My My user registration currently captures the First Name, Last Name, Email address, Country State and City. Is it possible to pull these information from the facebook profile once the user signs in through facebook and create their login in my database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this should be possible if you manually implement a so-called "Login Flow". Have a look at the docs at

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.0

There you can find a step-by-step guide on how to implement OAuth with Facebook.